# No WebClient Class in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, web, xamarin, namespaces, xamarin.forms

I am after the C# `WebClient` Class in Xamarin.Forms

The Documentation for the class is here:

- [System.Net.WebClient Class - Xamarin Forms](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Net.WebClient/)
- [System.Net.WebClient Class - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx)

I have imported the `System.Net` Namespace as per the requirement, but it comes up as an unnecessary namespace.
The `System.Net.WebClient` namespace is not available.

Is there anything I am missing? - The class should come up in the intellisense right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you say in "Xamarin.Forms", what project type is this? A PCL, the Android App, iOS App? Something else?

Let us assume that this is a Portable Class Library (PCL). In this case the answer is, NO.

PCL only provides a subset of the .NET Framework, which in this case does *not* contain WebClient. What should you use instead? What about, HttpClient?

A couple of compelling reasons to use HttpClient are:

1. Xamarin provides HttpClientHandlers for Android and iOS which leverage platform specific HTTP API's, such as NSUrlConnection on iOS.
2. HttpClient is a fully **async** API, which is great! We don't want to block the UI when fetching stuff.
3. It is super easy to use

A small sample for you:

```
static HttpClient _client = new HttpClient(); // you should reuse a HttpClient!

private async Task<string> FetchStuffAsync()
{
    using (var response = await _client.GetAsync("http://google.com"))
    {
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // Horray it went well!
            var page = await response.Content.GetStringAsync();
            return page;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

On top of HttpClient, you get all sorts of goodness, such as Refit and Fusilade. Then you can use Polly for circuit breaker or retry.

Conclusion:
Use HttpClient which is a contemporary .NET API, contrary to WebClient, which is ancient and has been in .NET since 1.1

Comment: Awesome I'll try that :-) and yes the project is PCL - forgot to mention that

Comment: HttpClient is great, one tip is to create a single instance for your app and keep reusing it, otherwise you don't get advantages of connection pooling etc

Comment: Is there any way we can handle the progress of uploading file, so that in case of large file we can display progress in percentage to the interface?

Comment: Yes, but it is not in the scope of this question. Please create a new one @JigneshPatel

Comment: @BillReiss how do you use a single HttpClient instance using Fusillade with different Priority settings?

Comment: @ledragon sounds like you want to open a new question

Comment: @Cheesebaron ha..yes maybe that's a better idea